# PHP SQL Pagination LIMIT clause

Tags: php, sql, limit

I am new to the whole php, sql, jquery. I am trying to paginate a sql gallery. I keep getting an error when using the sql LIMIT clause.

It either spits all the images out on one page but gives non functioning page number buttons OR only shows the selected number of items but doesnt create extra pages for the rest of the queries results.

I have searched for a solution and found that there was a problem with using variables after the LIMIT function. Can anyone either show me a better way to implement this or give me a solution to my problem.

```
    $items = 8; 

if(isset($_GET['page']) and is_numeric($_GET['page']) and $page = $_GET['page'])
             $limit = " LIMIT ".(($page-1)*$items).",$items";
          else
             $limit = " LIMIT $items";


if(empty($clothing) && empty($price) && empty($uploaded)) {    
$query = "SELECT path, description, filename  FROM category $limit";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

I have also tried this below which gives an error.

```
    $per_page = 8; 

if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
$page=$_GET['page'];
}
$start = ($page-1)*$per_page; 

if(empty($clothing) && empty($price) && empty($uploaded)) {
$query = "SELECT path, description, filename  FROM category LIMIT $start, $per_page ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-8, 8' at line 1.**

To shed more light the 'if' is to filter the queries results. This is just the first of many sql queries.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offset value for `LIMIT` cannot be negative